# Error SMTP 'error could not authenticate' usando PhpMailer

Tags: php, html

Deseo saber por que no puedo usar el servicio SMTP con otra cuenta que no sea la que originalmente use para prueba, el error no es de código ya que la primera cuenta si funciona correctamente, ¿Hay algo que deba configurar para que la segunda cuenta deje de lanzar el mensaje **error could not authenticate**? ¿Alguna configuración de la cuenta en Gmail? Ya active el permiso 'Permitir que aplicaciones menos seguras accedan a tu cuenta'.

¿Algo mas que deba hacer? ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Este es mi código php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>Formulario</title> <!-- Aquí va el título de la página -->
<script type="text/javascript">
      function submitForm() {
   // Get the first form with the name
   // Hopefully there is only one, but there are more, select the correct index
   var frm = document.getElementById('form1');
   frm.submit(); // Submit
   frm.reset();  // Reset
   return false; // Prevent page refresh
}
    </script>
        
</head>

<body>
<?php

$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Mensaje = $_POST['Mensaje'];
$Telefono = $_POST['Telefono'];    

if ($Nombre=='' || $Email=='' || $Mensaje=='' || $Telefono==''){

    echo "<script>alert('Los campos marcados con * son obligatorios');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

}else{


    require("archivosformulario/class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();    
    $mail->From     = $Email;
    $mail->FromName = $Nombre; 
    $mail->AddAddress("foo@gmail.com"); // Dirección a la que llegaran los mensajes.

    // Aquí van los datos que apareceran en el correo que reciba
    //adjuntamos un archivo 

    $mail->WordWrap = 50; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);     
    $mail->Subject  =  "Comentarios Tiendas El Golazo";
    $mail->Body     =  "Nombre: $Nombre \n<br />".    
    "Email: $Email \n<br />".    
    "Mensaje: $Mensaje \n<br />".
    "Telefono: $Telefono \n<br />";       

    // Datos del servidor SMTP

    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";  // Servidor de Salida.
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->Username = "foo@gmail.com";  // Correo Electrónico
    $mail->Password = "pwd"; // Contraseña

    if ($mail->Send())
    echo "<script>alert('Formulario enviado exitosamente, le responderemos lo más pronto posible.');
            location.href ='contactanos.html';
            </script>";    

    else
    echo "<script>alert('Error al enviar el formulario');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Dudo que sea de código debido a que una cuenta si funciona y otra no. Ayuda!

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Intenta cambiando la linea: `$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";` con las siguientes:`$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; $mail->Port = 465; $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` aunque el error que mencionas es debido al user y al password, revisa bien tus credenciales de la cuenta para acceder al servidor smtp

Comment: Excelente hermano te agradezco mucho!

Comment: Lo intenté pero no logro visualizar el check para ponerlo en verde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta cambiando la linea: `$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";` con las siguientes:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

aunque el error que mencionas es debido al user y al password, revisa bien las credenciales de la cuenta para acceder al servidor smtp.